# How can I adjust the style of the output from a .Rmd chunk?

Tags: r, r-markdown

Here is an example code chunk and it's output.

```
`{r example, message = F}
for (i in 1:5) {
  print(i)
}
`
```

[image]

I would like this to render in my output file without the border box, and without the leading `## [1]`. Is that possible?

Comment: first add `comment = ''` within the chunk options. and instead of `print(i)` use `cat(i, '\n')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution also removes the border box.

- Use the r chunk `comment` option to remove the `##` character.
- Use `cat()` instead of `print()` to display the output without the R formatting `[1]`. You need to specify in `cat()` that you want newlines added.
- One method to remove the border box would be to use css. You can use an external css file, or make a dedicated hidden chunk to specify it.

  - I noticed the code chunks and output chunks were both specified by the `<pre>` tag, with the code chunk being of class `.r`, and the output chunk being `.hljs`. These might change with different themes, but this selector worked for me. `pre.hljs` might work alternatively as a selector.

Below is a complete .Rmd file that can be knit to an html document

````
---
title: example.Rmd
output: html_document
---

```{css, echo = FALSE}
pre:not(.r) {
    border: 0px;
}
```

```{r, comment = ""}
for (i in 1:5) {
  cat(i, "\n")
}
```
````

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code

```
{r example, message = FALSE, comment = ''}
 for (i in 1:5) {
   cat(i, '\n')
}
```